# RoR 3 - authentication with Authorization combined with Facebook Connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, facebook, authorization

I'd like to know what would be the best "practise" to use:

- Authentication
- Authorization
- Facebook connect

I have seen authlogic has an Facebook Connect plugin.
But the roles (authorization) haven't been described there.

How would i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use an authorization plugin in addition to Authlogic. like cancan

Comment: +1 for the use of cancan gem as an authorisation system. Check http://github.com/ryanb/cancan